# Можно ли использовать другие типы карты на iOS: спутник, гибрид?

Tags: yandexmapkit

Появивилась ли возможность переключать типы карты? Судя по ответам на гите в планах этого не было и в релиз ноутах версий такой функционал не появлялся

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что его нужно задавть поддержке сервиса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/feedback/concepts/faq.html#about__general) явно прописано:

*Какие типы карт доступны в MapKit?*
**В MapKit доступны только карты с типом «схема» и пользовательские слои карт.**

Это обусловлено условиями лицензий, по которым Яндекс использует сторонние спутниковые снимки. Подобные изменения будут явно прописаны в доке и релизнотах, если лицензирование изменится.